# Remove empty query string parameter from Google Analytics

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics, query-string

I was wondering if anyone knows how to remove an empty query string parameter from Google Analytics?

An example URL would be: http://www.domain.com/index.asp?a=test&b=test&c=&d=test

On this example I would want Google Analytics to filter out "c" because it's empty.

Thanks for any help that can be provided!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expending upon @user1494396; refactor your async tracking code to pass the page name from the regex like so:

```
(function (window) {
    function cleanQs() {
        if (!window.location.search) {
            return window.location.pathname;
        }
        var locSearchArr = window.location.search.match(/[^\=\&\?]+=[^\=\&\?]+/g);
        var locPathName = window.location.pathname;
        if (locSearchArr && locSearchArr.length > 0) {
            locPathName += "?" + locSearchArr.join("&");
        }
        return locPathName;
    }

    var _gaq = window._gaq || (window._gaq = []);
    window._gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
    window._gaq.push(['_trackPageview', cleanQs()]);
})(this);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

See:

- [Google's Async Tracking Code Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncTracking) for more info on the base of the code
- [JSFiddle Demo of this code](http://jsfiddle.net/TomFuertes/pCF8s/)

Answer (score 0):

`"http://www.domain.com/index.asp?a=test&b=test&c=&d=test".match(/[^\=\&\?]+=[^\=\&\?]+/g)` --JavaScript

should return an array of ["a=test","b=test","d=test"].